# To bind a Element/Object to be available to jQuery.post callback (better way?)

Tags: jquery

I have this function in charge of making a ajax call, and based on the response, change a HTML Element

The thing is.. I need to know the know which element triggered the call when the callback happen.
The way it is right now, seems to be working (have tested only in Chrome); but for some reason it does not appear for me being a 'jQuery way' of doing it.

```
function accept_order(e){
  var target = $(e.currentTarget)
  $.post('painel_restaurante/accept_order', 
    {
      authenticity_token: j('[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
      id: target.parents('tr').attr('data-order-id')
    }, 
    function(resp, status, xhr){
      if(resp && resp.length && resp[0] == true ){
        alert(xhr.element)     // <-- attention here
      }
    },
    'json'
  ).element = target           // <-- and attention here

  return false;
}
$('.action_button.accept').click( accept_order );
```

**Is this a good way? Any suggestion for something better?**

*The same logic of this applies to .ajax and .get, I'd recommend to have this sort of example in the official API*

**EDIT+**
[Screenshot CLOSURE, where?](http://twitpic.com/4sy83c) <-- Chrome debugger FAIL.
Actually, using console.log() would show the variable defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the beauty of Javascript; you can simply access variable `target` in the success function because of the closure.

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet of that? I get `undefined` if use `target` inside the callback :/

Comment: Your answer were right, even though the debugger would show otherwise. -updated